# Feature Timelines, why can I not see the child iterations?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

We have iterations:
2003/a, 2003/b, 2003/c, 2003/d, 2003/e
and
2004/a, 2004/b, 2004/c, 2004/d, 2004/e

But the Feature Timeline is only showing columns 2003 and 2004, I'd expect to see a breakdown by child iteration.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your screenshot, seems you were using [Feature timeline and Epic Roadmap](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.workitem-feature-timeline-extension) extension.

It's caused by you are using a team based backlog/ Feature Timeline, not a project level.

[image]

### How to select team-level iteration:

1. You already created corresponding child iterations  under the whole project.

[image]

2. But you still need to select them in related teams.

Click **the default team's settings**  in you screenshot. You could also switch team in the drop down list:

[image]

3.select iteration you need for the team

[image]
4. Now you will be able to see child iteration in feature pipeline.
[image]

Comment: Great answer. Not very intuitive though.

Answer (score 1):

Your screen is a page with team project settings. You have to go through the link in the section:

> To select iterations for the team, go to **the default team's settings**.

Then add all child iterations to the team iterations: [Select team sprints and set the default iteration path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/set-iteration-paths-sprints?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#select-team-sprints-and-set-the-default-iteration-path).